# Add submenu in menupopup mozilla extension developmet?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Here I am working with firefox extension development. I have using **XUL Overlays**  to add menu popup item in my extension.

```
          <menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup"> 
             <menuitem label="HP Scheduler Options..."
                       insertafter="devToolsSeparator" 
                       oncommand="openPreferences('hpschedPane');" />
           </menupopup>
```

Here I need to add sub menu with menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<menupopup id="menu_ToolsPopup"> 
  <menuitem label="HP Scheduler Options..."
    insertafter="devToolsSeparator" 
    oncommand="openPreferences('hpschedPane');" />
  <menu id="..." label="My submenu!">
    <menupopup>
      <menuitem label="My menu item in the submenu!" oncommand="..." />
    </menupopup>
  </menu>
</menupopup>
```